Bulk remove many-to-many entries?
Well consider I have 1000s of users, those users are used in a many-to-many relation with "companies".
Now I wish to remove all users which are "inactive" (which is the majority) from the company list.
There is the trick I could use with remove:
for user in User.filter(active=False):
    Company.customers.remove(user)

However this would do also 1000s of database hits, making it really really slow. Is there a way I can do this in django? Without going to rawsql?

making it really really slow, "slow" is an opinion, not something you can measure. How much time does it actually take for a single user? And how many users you have to delete? And where does your application spend its time? Is there some index that could improve performance?

It's a command that is executed very seldomly, however it is breaking django/azure connection at customer databases.. Due to privacy I cannot provide (nor do I know as developer) the exact details, only the server logs that it takes 10+ minutes to do this for every company for every user.

Why "Without going to rawsql"?

that it takes 10+ minutes to do this for every company for every user Deleting a single users takes 10+ minutes? I would say 10 seconds would be extremely long, but 10 minutes is just amazing. Looks like you have bigger problems than just this delete. It's just that the delete shows you the issue. Check your queries, check the query plans and improve your index strategies. Looks like there is a lot to win.

All this "opera buffa" can be reduced to this simple, fast and straightforward delete from users where not active and company_id = ? cascade.

@FrankHeikens of course not a single user, it's deleting 1000s of users-company fields.. And I notice especially the getter for users gets a lot of extra data.

@Stefanov.sm: Stefanov.sm: I don't think the inactive users itself should be removed, but the m2m relations that are binding it.

@willeM_VanOnsem Well, quote the OP "I wish to remove all users which are "inactive" (which is the majority) from the company list" (bold mine). Yet removing the m2m relations only is a trivial query too.

@Stefanov.sm: you forgot the next part: "from the company list". So not the users itself, but from a list (likely the customers) hold by a Company.

I think the main reason why one does not want to do raw SQL is because Django is (to some extent) dialect-indepedent, The models can also eventually map to tables with a different name (you can rename the table in the future), and even be across multiple databases.

@willeM_VanOnsem Still trivial and much clearer to read delete from the_bridge_table tbd where exists (select from users where user_id = rbd.id and company_id = ?). As for native SQL use and portability, please note that SQL is a widely accepted and well established standard that encourages good data designs while Django is by far not.

@Stefanov.sm: I don't know Company.customers.through.objects.filter(user__active=False).delete() tells exactly what it is doing, it has an equivalent of "noise" bits I would guess. It works even if the User table is located at a different database. If later you change the name of the table or the columns of the database it still works, and it will work on all sorts of databases (postgreSQL, mongoDB, MySQL, etc.) because it is dialect-independent.

@willeM_VanOnsem My understanding is to use the right tool for the job, a data tool for a data-centric job in this particular case. "One-size-fits-all-usisex" does work most of the time but it does not look good indeed, does it?

@Stefanov.sm: well the task here is a webserver, where the administration of the companies and users is one of the tasks the webservers does. The idea of using models is that you can use these to deserialize data you get from the database, automatically making and migrating tables alongside these models, etc. So the work is in creating the models, and the ORM to talk to the database. This administrative task is thus a very small step and doing this would require also writing logic to open a cursor, etc.

But the more fundamental problem with SQL is that it was designed as interaction with humans, whereas nowadays machines talk to it. This was not the initial scope of SQL, and SQL injection was therefore something never really anticipated. The sad thing is that a lot of webservers still seem to do raw SQL formatting, which makes a lot of server infrastructure quite vulnerable.

But @willeM_VanOnsem, why shall we accept that the lack of education be a plausible argument when discussing engineering? I really doubt that having a declarative nature makes SQL designed for interaction with humans. This (and ORM use motivarion as well) might be true in the late nineties, but a quarter of a century passed since then.

@Stefanov.sm: well I think the main problem is that object-oriented program is just a bad idea. In my spare time, I never use OO programming: declarative Haskell :). But I find the "lack of education" argument quite strange. The entire idea of software engineering is to make systems fool-proof, so if you need more education, then clearly something went wrong. The main idea of pure functional programming languages that is key, are monads, that thus prevents functions having side-effects. Not because of good education, but simply because the design of the language does not allow that.

@willeM_VanOnsem I share some of your ideas, others - well, not that much.  Anyway, a good talk.

Remove the elements in bulk:
Company.customers.remove(*User.objects.filter(active=False))
This will make two queries: one to get the primary keys (or the field referenced by the ManyToManyField) of the User objects, and then remove all these elements in bulk.
If you want to do this for all Companys, you can use:
# 🖟 reference to the Company model
Company.customers.through.objects.filter(user__active=False).delete()
if we want to work with a specific Company, we can also limit the number of queries slightly more with:
# 🖟 reference to the Company model
Company.customers.through.objects.filter(
    company=some_company, user__active=False
).delete()

Wouldn't that first get all users still? Even though I just need pk data (user model is huge, getting the amount of users would be like 2-10 MB).

@paul23: it will make two hits, one for the User objects, and then one to remove all items in bulk: https://github.com/django/django/blob/4636baec179d8733e92c1eccfa669bd72d739735/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py#L914

If you are doing this for a lot of companies, you can reuse the queryset of Users, so then it is once per Company. If you want to do this for all companies, we can speed it up further to just two queries for all Companys and Users.
